# Connecting remote client to Phoenix channel

Tags: reactjs, websocket, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

I'm trying to separate my front end from Phoenix 1.3 (localhost:4000) and I'm running a React on localhost:3000.

I cannot for the life of me connect to Phoenix.  I get the error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:4000/socket/websocket?token=undefined&vsn=2.0.0' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I'm using the following client side:

```
let socket = new Socket("ws://localhost:4000/socket", {params: {token: window.userToken}})

    socket.connect();

    // Now that you are connected, you can join channels with a topic:
    let channel = socket.channel("coin:lobby", {});
    channel
      .join()
      .receive("ok", resp => {
        console.log("Joined successfully", resp);
      })
      .receive("error", resp => {
        console.log("Unable to join", resp);
      });
```

I can manage to connect using wsta in terminal and I receive a good response.  I thought it was potentially some sort of CORS issue, but I've implemented the `cors_plug` elixir lib and I'm still having the issue.  Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

you have to first install phoenix client

`npm install phoenix --save`

```js
    import {Socket} from "phoenix"; // in your component 
    let socket = new Socket("ws://localhost:4000/socket");

    socket.connect();
    let channel = socket.channel("chat_room:lobby", {});
    console.log(channel);
```

The same problems i also faced and resolved it with same code.

please ref this [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-realtime-feed-using-phoenix-and-react--cms-29122)